# 1020x1080 Touchscreen driver

Tags: touchscreen, driver

I want to install the LCD-show driver to my raspberry Pi. But the touchscreen I have to use has a 1920 x 1080 resolution. I havent found a way to get the driver for this resolution. 
Is there somekind of an alternative?

Comment: the LCD-show drivers are for specific screens, you need to know what the driver is for the touch screen you are using first and install or enable that, then you need to calibrate it. the LCD-show just makes this easy by knowing what to set up for specific screens

Comment: I use a Dell S2240T 21.5 Multi-Touch Monitor. I haven't found a linux driver for this screen.

Comment: you may find that it is supported already, have you tried just plugging it in? what OS are you using? if its plugged in and you right click something to get a context menu up, if you then touch the screen does the menu disappear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now used this driver from [git](https://github.com/bsteinsbo/rpi_touch_driver). It works perfectly fine with the Dell Monitor and the desired resolution.